# How to write a .vimrc function to match a filename in a given file and open it with the vsplit command?

Tags: vim

I have a file called `Index.txt` with the following lines:

```
/Project/A/B/C/D/main.c
/Project/A/B/C/D/main_backend.c
/Project/A/B/C/D/main_frontend.c
```

I'd like to create a command called `Fsearch` to execute a search in `Index.txt` using regular expressions, match **the first occurrence** and execute `:vsplit` with it. For example, if I execute:

```
:Fsearch main_backend.c
```

Vim should execute:

```
:vsplit /Project/A/B/C/D/main_backend.c
```

and If I execute:

```
:Fsearch main*.c
```

Vim should execute:

```
:vsplit /Project/A/B/C/D/main.c
```

This is what I've tried so far but I'm pretty sure it could be improved:

```
function! CopyMatches(reg)  
let l:file = grep -m 1 a:reg ~/Index.txt
echom l:file
if len(l:file) > 0
    exec ':vsp ' . l:file
else
echom 'File not found: ' . l:file
end
endfunction  
command! -nargs=* Fsearch call CopyMatches('<args>')
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
function! CopyMatches(reg)
   execute "silent! grep!" a:reg " ~/Index.txt"
   redraw!
   let l:file = getqflist()
   if len(l:file) > 0
       let l:path_head = fnamemodify( "~/workspace", ":p" )
       for l:item in l:file
           let l:current_file = l:path_head . "/" . l:item["text"]  
           if match( l:current_file, getcwd() ) != -1 
               execute 'vsplit' fnamemodify( l:current_file, ":~:.")
               return
           endif
        endfor
        echom "File not found:" a:reg
   else
      echom "File not found:" a:reg
   endif
endfunction

command! -nargs=* Fsearch call CopyMatches('<args>')
```

Explanation:

- The `:grep` built-in command is a wrap used by Vim to execute an external `grep` (see [`:help grep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#:grep) for more information).
- The `:grep!` form of the `:grep` command doesn't jump to the first match automatically (i.e., `:grep!` won't open `Index.txt`).
- The `:silent!` command is used to suppress the default full screen grep output.
- Vim uses `quickfix list` with `:grep` so you can get all occurrences from `getqflist()` function (see [`:help getqflist()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getqflist%28%29) for details)

Comment: Thanks it works gr8. With your earlier solution if I want to change the line execute "silent! grep!" a:reg " ~/Index.txt" to execute "silent! grep!" a:reg " ~/cscope.files" | "grep `cut -d/ -f 5- <<<"${PWD}"`" . So that I can get only relative result always. plz Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: `system("pwd | cut -d/ -f 5-".expand("%"))` giving desired search string I wanna use so I tried `execute "silent! grep!" a:reg " ~/cscope.files" | exe "silent! grep" system("pwd | cut -d/ -f 5-".expand("%"))` but it keep on running after doing Ctrl+c its giving error `E486: pattern not found :dev`

Comment: say my $pwd is /home/user/workspace/Project_1/A/B/C/
    for now `:Fsearch main*.c`
    say I am getting following result (i am not using -m1 in grep)
    /home/user/workspace/Project_1/A/B/main.c
    /home/user/workspace/Project_1/A/B/C/main_backend.c
    /home/user/workspace/Project_1/A/B/C/D/main_frontend.c
    /home/user/workspace/Project_1/A/main_common.c
    But I want `:Fsearch main*.c` should fetch only result i.e w.r.t. $pwd
    /home/user/workspace/Project_1/A/B/C/main_backend.c
    /home/user/workspace/Project_1/A/B/C/D/main_frontend.c

Comment: It always telling file not found.  
    I printed the `l:current_file` just below `echom "File not found:" a:reg`  
    It showing `l:current_file /users/user1./Project_1/A/main_common.c`  
    instead it should have this value `Project_1/A/main_common.c`  
    And before redraw! it printing  `/users/user1/Index.txt:10:./Project_1/A/main_common.c`

Comment: Now I removed `./` i.e period slash at start of each line of `Index.txt` but added print is printing the value of `l:current_file /users/user1Project_1/A/main_common.c` i.e vsplit trying to open `vsplit /users/user1Project_1/A/main_common.c` thats why it return always file not found, instead it should open `vsplit Project_1/A/main_common.c`

Comment: Ok. How about now.

Comment: Now it's opening every file w.r.t. to the location of Index.txt (which is at different location than project code location) and then concatenating with the exact line we searched from Index.txt i.e `/users/user1/Project_1/A/B/C/main_backend.c` instead it should open w.r.t. relative path from `$pwd`. Say my `$pwd` is `workspace/Project_1/A/B/C`
now after doing :Fsearch `main*.c`
it should execute `vsplit main_backend.c` as C has `main_backend.c`
but if C does not have `main*.c` but if D has the `main*.c` i.e `main_frontend.c` then it should open `vsplit D/main_frontend.c`.

Comment: Ok. It's necessary to provide the directory `index.txt` is referring to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are gr8.